# method to play music within javafx project does not cause music to play

Tags: java, javasound

I created a method to try and play music during a JavaFX game, I placed a print line of code to state if it's playing the file which it does print to the console correctly stating that it is playing the music file, except I don't hear any music playing.

The game runs fine, and the music file is inside the project folder in its proper place, and I called the `method music("song.wav");` inside the start method. All the import statements are there and the scene is able to play out as well.

```java
// called inside start method 
music("song.wav");
```

and here's the method

```java
private void music(String musicLocation) {
    try {
        //take WAV file as input for background music
        File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
        //checks if the music file exists in project's path
        if (musicPath.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The game is playing: " + musicPath);
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.start();

            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: This isn't related to JavaFX.  You are using standard javax. (no 'f') audio APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't [associating your AudioInputStream with the Clip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#open(javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream)).

Try:

```
        AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioinput);
        clip.start();
```

Comment: oh wow one line of code really fixed it! thanks again for the help!

Comment: *cough .. how about formatting links as ... links? That button on top of the editor helps ... :)